# Can you hide certain file types on GitHub's Pull Request page?

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension, pull-request

The current project that I am working on uses Jest snapshots and as it is in the early days still, the snapshots are constantly changing. These new snapshots are filling up my PRs and when diffing files I need to either scroll past them (they tend to be long files) or go through the page at the start and minimize them all manually.

Is there a feature in GitHub or a Chrome extension that would allow me to automatically filter these files out? Even just minimize them?

I've tried [Pretty Pull Requests](https://github.com/Yatser/prettypullrequests) but I can't seem to get it working to recognize the `.snap` files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple expand / collapse function in the *Files Changed* view of GitHub will not work? They explained the issue here --> [Collapse / Expand files in the Files Changed view of a Pull Request](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/514)
Otherwise the [refined-github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github) extension will maybe help.

Edit with @robdonn comment: *Though the collapse/expand function in the refined-github is removed. [Previously part of refined-github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github#previously-part-of-refined-github)*

Comment: The problem with the current implementation is that you have to manually expand/collapse the files, there does not appear to be any way of doing it automatically based on filenames or even just in groups.

Also refined-github [removed their collapse/expand feature](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github#previously-part-of-refined-github)